# Undefined variable en view edit Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Cuando quiero ingresar a editar un registro, me salta el siguiente error:

**Undefined variable: pmedicamento (View: E:\CursoLaravel\sisMSP\resources\views\PMedicamentos\edit.blade.php)**

No logro encontrar la solución a ello.

En mi controller, en la función de edit tengo lo siguiente:

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $pmedicamento=PMedicamentos::findOrFail($id);

        $departamentos = DB::table('departamentos')->get();

        $medicamentosp = DB::table('medicamentos')->get();

        $prestadores = DB::table('prestador_seguro')->get();

        $laboratorios = DB::table('laboratorios')->get();

        $solicitud = DB::table('tipo_solicitud')->get();

        return view("PMedicamentos.edit", [
            "departamentos" => $departamentos,
            "medicamentos" => $medicamentosp,
            "prestadores" => $prestadores,
            "laboratorios" => $laboratorios,
            "solicitud" => $solicitud
        ]);
    }
```

El error me lo marca en la parte del titulo Editar Paciente de la vista edit, alli está la variable:

```
@extends ('layouts.admin')
@section ('contenido')
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <h3>Editar Paciente: {{$pmedicamento->CI}}</h3>
            @if (count($errors)>0)
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <ul>
                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                    <li>{{$error}}</li>
                @endforeach
                </ul>
            </div>
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>
            {!!Form::model($pmedicamento,['method'=>'PATCH','route'=>['PMedicamentos.update',$pmedicamento->idpmed], 'files'=>'true'])!!}
            {{Form::token()}}
```

Tambien dejo aqui el create y store:

```
public function create()

    {
        $departamentos = DB::table('departamentos')->get();

        $medicamentosp = DB::table('medicamentos')->get();

        $prestadores = DB::table('prestador_seguro')->get();

        $laboratorios = DB::table('laboratorios')->get();

        $solicitud = DB::table('tipo_solicitud')->get();

        return view("PMedicamentos.create", [
            "departamentos" => $departamentos,
            "medicamentos" => $medicamentosp,
            "prestadores" => $prestadores,
            "laboratorios" => $laboratorios,
            "solicitud" => $solicitud
        ]);
    }

    public function store (PMedicamentosFormRequest $request)
    {

            $pmedicamento=new PMedicamentos;
            $pmedicamento->CI=$request->get('CI');
            $pmedicamento->Primer_Nombre=$request->get('Primer_Nombre');
            $pmedicamento->Primer_Apellido=$request->get('Primer_Apellido');
            $pmedicamento->Departamento=$request->get('Departamento');
            $pmedicamento->idmedicamento=$request->get('idmedicamento');
            $pmedicamento->idprestador=$request->get('idprestador');
            $pmedicamento->idlaboratorio=$request->get('idlaboratorio');
            $pmedicamento->N_Sentencia=$request->get('N_Sentencia');
            $pmedicamento->Fecha_Sentencia=$request->get('Fecha_Sentencia');
            $pmedicamento->Tipo_Solicitud=$request->get('Tipo_Solicitud');
            $pmedicamento->Condicion='1';
            $pmedicamento->save();

            return Redirect::to('PMedicamentos.index');
    }
```

Agradezco sus comentarios y si es necesario que suba algo mas del codigo solo avisen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si no pasas la variable entre los valores del segundo parámetro del helper view(), sin duda alguna aparecerá el error de variable no definida:

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $pmedicamento = PMedicamentos::findOrFail($id);

    $departamentos = DB::table('departamentos')->get();

    $medicamentosp = DB::table('medicamentos')->get();

    $prestadores = DB::table('prestador_seguro')->get();

    $laboratorios = DB::table('laboratorios')->get();

    $solicitud = DB::table('tipo_solicitud')->get();

    return view("PMedicamentos.edit", [
        "pmedicamento" => $pmedicamento,
        "departamentos" => $departamentos,
        "medicamentos" => $medicamentosp,
        "prestadores" => $prestadores,
        "laboratorios" => $laboratorios,
        "solicitud" => $solicitud
    ]);
}
```